# Why use Enzyme with Jest when they seem to do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I am looking at setting up frontend unit tests for a react app and a lot of the guides say to install both Jest and Enzyme but when reading the descriptions for Jest and Enzyme I can't work out what Enzyme does that Jest doesn't already do other than "its just better if you use both".

Are there any important features I would be missing out on if I just use Jest for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jest` provides the test framework, assertion library, and with its default configuration it also provides a browser-like test environment using `jsdom`.

So it provides a lot.

[`Enzyme`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) enhances that by providing...

> a JavaScript Testing utility for React that makes it easier to test your React Components' output. You can also manipulate, traverse, and in some ways simulate runtime given the output.

`Enzyme` makes it easier to render your components, query them, test their state, output, etc.

It's not the only library that helps with rendering `React` components (there's also `ReactTestUtils` and [`react-testing-library`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library) in addition to `Enzyme`...which are [all mentioned in the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html)), but it's a very good one.